# Why is the serial port component missing from my Visual Studio toolbox?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

[serial port not seen in components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdok8.png)

I'm working on a windows form application but I can't find the needed SerialPort component in my toolbox. Tried resetting the toolbox but it didn't work either.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-on-net-core-windows-forms-designer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output tab of the Visual Studio on your screenshot, suggests that your project is a .NET Core project. To check this go to the project properties and check the Target Framework setting.
SerialPort, you are expecting to see in the toolbox, is a component that is a part of the .NET framework which is different from the .NET Core

If you want to keep using .NET Core as your platform try with the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/

Comment: Since OP question is about VSCode as it stands now you probably want to adjust question or answer to math one another...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Indeed. The question says VSCode but the tag and the screenshot suggest that it's a Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I did what you said and it works completely fine now, sorry that I wrote the question wrong as it ought to be Visual Studio.

Comment: @ElTen11 Welcome. If this solves your problem please accept the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I spent whole day to solve this problem. When you first create a project  as an .NET Core (3.0 3.1 or NET5.0) project, you can't (easily) change it to the .NET Framework. You have to choose .net framework (not .net core version) at the beginning!

[correct project type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EZQ.jpg)

Than the SerialPort will be availabe at the defaut.

Answer (score 0):

Its solution is pretty simple:
When creating project:
Use .Net Frame work instead of .Net core
[image: : Check this Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

In my case I changed the Visual Studio Version from 2022 to 2017